# At what point should a difficult puzzle be answered by the author, if at all?

Tags: discussion

Possibly an unnecessary question, but curiosity got the best of me.

My [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110424/weaponized-riddles-2-dishing-it-out) hasn't been answered for almost 2 weeks. I'm a bit impatient and I'm waiting for someone to answer it so I can work on the next part of the puzzle.

This sparked a question, not exactly for this puzzle, but in general.

Is there ever a point in time where a question has been **too hard** (or maybe, too **inactive**), that it's best for the author to **give the answer away**?
Whether it be for the *satisfaction of finding the answer*, or just a *new way to look* at the puzzle.
If there is, when do you think that point should be and **why**? If not...**why not**?

*If this is a duplicate question, I'll remove it promptly. Just let me know.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/how-long-should-i-wait-before-providing-the-answer-to-my-riddle) Also see https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6180/ https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6927/ https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5863/ https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6019/ , and more