# How to deal with old unanswered puzzles?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[I have a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116756/the-cryptic-safe) that was posted back on June 22nd of this year. The first partial answer was posted a day later (6/23), and was last edited the day after that (6/24). The last comment on that answer was 6/25. The last activity on that post from someone other than me was 7/8, a comment asking for another hint. A bounty for 200rep was started 7/14, and ended 7/22. My last edit consisted of me simply adding a note at the top asking people to let me know where they are stuck so that I could provide proper/needed hints. It has now been about 17 days since the last comment, 6 days since my last edit (on 7/19), and just over a month of the puzzle as a whole going unsolved.

**My main question is:** How do you know when your puzzle is still being worked on, or when everyone has given up?

**Some follow up questions:**

- If you believe the puzzle has been given up on, should you add more hints or reveal a partial answer?
- What's the best way to bring more attention to your puzzle?
- What's the best way to check if somebody is still working towards a solution?
- Is there a good way to promote engagement on your puzzle, without purposely spamming to be bumped to the top of the home page?

I understand that a month without an answer isn't extremely long, especially not for a puzzle of the complexity which mine is, however I do believe these are good questions to ask of any puzzle. I understand that there probably are not concrete answers to most of these, but just getting some insight to the general best practices for cases like this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would occasionally checking the "Viewed ? times" be good enough?

Comment: [This](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5863/best-practice-for-puzzles-that-have-fallen-silent) might help, I believe it answers your questions

Comment: @Auribouros I must have missed that link while searching, thank you! Definitely helpful :)